# Ensuring constant figure size when using matplotlib colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis, image-resizing, colorbar

I'm creating multiple plots with a colorbar in `matplotlib`, saving them in tight layout. I noticed that the size of the figures and the size of the axes differ for each image because the colorbar takes more/less space depending on the number of decimals of the data. For example, consider this script:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

order = 0

x = np.tile(np.arange(10), 10).reshape((10,10))
y = np.repeat(np.arange(10),10).reshape((10,10))
z = np.sort(np.random.rand(100)*10**order).reshape((10,10))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))
cs = ax.pcolor(x,y,z)

cbar = plt.colorbar(cs)
plt.tight_layout()

fig.savefig(f'order_{order}.jpg', bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

Running this with `order=-3` and `order=0` gives the below figures, which evidently have (a) different sizes and (b) differently sized axis for the main plot.

[image]
[image]

**How can I ensure that the images and the axes are the same size regardless of the number of decimals of the data?** I know that my data has at most 3 decimals. I tried using the `fraction` argument on the colorbar to "reserve" space, but the value has no effect when doing `bbox_inches='tight`. I essentially need to maintain some padding on the right side of the figure.

Comment: You should almost always use constrained layout rather than tight.  It deals with colorbars.  However, it won't help with your underlying problem, which is that the colorbar tick labels are different sizes on different calls.  Nothing automatic will, because how does one figure know what you will plot in a future figure?  You will have to do something manual.  I would also not use bbox_inches='tight' if it was important that the figure stays the same size.

Answer (score 1):

I have found one method, use `plt.tight_layout()` but afterwards re-add padding on the right, i.e.

```
plt.tight_layout()
plt.subplots_adjust(right = 0.9)
```

It does require an empirical value for `right` though, so I am interested in other options.